# Feel strange. Hiding Activex combobox in some name doesn't work

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Activex combobox named "`Start_EX_Item_Catalog_CatalogGenre`" and this code `ActiveSheet.Shapes("Start_EX_Item_Catalog_CatalogGenre").Visible = False` doesn't work, any help?

I can hide it when I name it before "`Start_EX_Item_Catalog_CatalogGen`", no more longer.

Excel 2007

Runtime Error -2147024809 (80070057)

Thank you.

Comment: What does "I can hide it when I name it before `Start_EX_Item_Catalog_CatalogGen`, no more longer." mean?  Post the code of your macro, because `ActiveSheet.Shapes("Start_EX_Item_Catalog_CatalogGenre").Visible = False` works in Excel 2007.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is very simple.

ActiveX Object on a worksheet must start with a letter and can be a maximum of 32 characters — including letters, numbers, and underscores (_).

The length of `Start_EX_Item_Catalog_CatalogGenre` is 34.

And hence `Start_EX_Item_Catalog_CatalogGen` which is 32 characters work but `Start_EX_Item_Catalog_CatalogGenre` doesn't

You can name the controls with more than 32 characters and Excel won't complain but it will not let you use that name in the code.